# Integration solution needed with rational powers of $x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I want to solve the following integration $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n/2}e^{-x}}{(x-1)^{m}}dx$$ where $n,m$ are positive integers. I can solve this integral if the limits are from $0 \to 1$ but I am unable to solve it for $0\to \infty$. I will be thankful to you for your help.

Comment: In which sense can you solve it from $0\to1$? Due to the singularity of the integrand at $x=1$, it's divergent for positive $m$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector the formula 3.385 of Gradshteyn and Rhezhik can be used to solve the above integral from $0 \to 1$. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @ProfessorVector your comment has confused me. Suppose if $n=4$ and $m=4$ then the indefinite integral is given in the following link (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+x%5E2e%5E(-x)%2F(x-1)%5E4). But the limits can be evaluated easily. Where is the problem?

Comment: That formula contains $(1-x)^{\lambda-1}$ **but** also the limitation $\operatorname{Re}\lambda>0$. In your case, you have $\lambda=1-m\le0$. Your confusion must have been there, before: how do you plan to divide by $0^3$? The singularity is also present in the graphs you linked to.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I am using the $(1-\beta x)^{-some symbol}$ part and $\lambda=1$ for my case. Also I request you to comment on my previous comment about the convergence problem. Thank you.

Comment: Read the limitation for $\beta$. Do you really think $\beta=1$ qualifies?

Comment: @ProfessorVector the limitation on $\beta$ is stated as $|arg(1-\beta)|<\pi$ so when I have $\beta=1$ then the $arg(1-\beta)|=0$ which is less than $\pi$. By the way please comment on my convergence question also. Thank you.

Comment: I think it is easy to prove the divergence of the integral for even $m$ by lower bounding the integral with the integration around $x=1$, the singularity.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I completely agree with you about the singularity that is present in that graph. But we can also see $f(x)+constant$ as the answer of indefinite integral in that link. And that $f(x)$ can be easily evaluated for $x=0$ as well as $x=\infty$. So my question is why does the divergence vanishes when we put the limits in the analytical expression of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

*This is not an answer but a result a CAS produced.*$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n/2}e^{-x}}{(x-1)^{m}}dx=\, _1F_1\left(m;m-\frac{n}{2};-1\right) \Gamma
   \left(-m+\frac{n}{2}+1\right)-\frac{\pi  (-1)^{-m} \Gamma (1-m) \,
   _1F_1\left(\frac{n}{2}+1;-m+\frac{n}{2}+2;-1\right) \left((-1)^m \csc
   \left(\pi  m-\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)+\csc \left(\frac{\pi 
   n}{2}\right)\right)}{\Gamma \left(-\frac{n}{2}\right) \Gamma
   \left(-m+\frac{n}{2}+2\right)}$$ But, take care : this is valid for $\Re(n)>-2\land \Re(m)<1$

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. But do you have any idea about the steps that are carried out to obtain the result?

Comment: BTW I checked on the wolphram alpha and it does not provide such an answer. It says no mathematical form solution available

Comment: @FrankMoses. If I had an $\epsilon$ of an idea, I would not have written the first line !

Comment: @FrankMoses. Wolfram Alpha does not do everything. Made by human beings for  human beings.

Comment: your software is really amazing I guess.

Comment: The OP wrote that $m$ is a positive integer, so there won't be much luck with $\Gamma(1-m)$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector. I fully agree with you, for sure ! I added the conditions.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I guess your answer is not valid for my question then

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici did you write it correctly that $R(n)>-2$. if we have (n=4) then we will have $\Gamma(-2)$